# Unable to find JMS Destination in JNDI'

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-integration-bus

I am trying to create queues and topics in Active MQ using below,  also it is able to create the queue in ActiveMQ, but when i am trying to run my message flow I am seeing couple of errors in eventviewer

```
( ACENODE03.IS01 ) ACE JMSClient. ''Broker 'ACENODE03'; Execution Group 'IS01'; Message Flow 'com.smm.CASEINIT'; Node 'JMS Input::ComIbmJMSClientInputNode' '' There is a configuration problem with the JNDI Administered objects where:  Initial Context Factory  = ''org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory''.  Location of the bindings = ''tcp://lzbita187879as:61616''.  ConnectionFactory Name   = ''ConnectionFactory''.  JMS destination  = ''CASEINIT''.  The exception text is : '' javax.naming.NameNotFoundException : CASEINIT, Unable to find JMS Destination in JNDI''.   

The node cannot obtain a JNDI Administered Object, because some of the values specified are incorrect.   

Check the JNDI Administered configuration for the JMS provider used by the node.   
  Either:   
  Modify the JNDI Administered objects and rebuild the bindings   
  or   
  Change the policy attributes associated with this JMS Provider and restart the integration server   
  or   
  Change the node attributes and redeploy the message flow.
```

Comment: How is IBM MQ related here?

Comment: How are you configuring your JNDI lookup?

Comment: From the names I assume you use ACE; can you show the JMSProviders policy file?

Comment: @JustinBertram
I am using IBM ACE message flow, where i have configured input node, and provided dynamicQueues by providing below in the properties                                                                      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Initial Context Factory = ''org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory''. Location of the bindings = ''tcp://lzbita187879as:61616''. ConnectionFactory Name = ''ConnectionFactory''. JMS destination = ''CASEINIT''.

Comment: looks like i had duplicate policies, i removed them and it is working as expected. Thank you